# Prove that the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Z}$ is noetherian and non-artinian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm trying to solve the following problem. Any feedback and help would be greatly appreciated!

Let $M$ be a module over a commutative ring. If every increasing (resp. decreasing) sequence of $A$-submodules of $M$ terminates after finite steps, the $A$-module $M$ is called noetherian (resp. Artinian)

(a) Prove that the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Z}$ is noetherian and non-artinian.

**My solution:**
To show that $M$ is noetherian we note every submodule can be represented as $(n)$ for some integer $n$. To see that this is the case let $n$ be the nonzero element of $M'$ with the smallest magnitude. Then since $M'$ is a module, it follows that $(n) \subset M'$. On the other hand if $x \in M'$ such that $n \nmid x$ then the remainder $r = x \mod n$ is nonzero and smaller than $n$. Since $M'$ is a module, we must have $r \in M$, but this contradicts the definition of $n$. Thus every submodule of $M$ can be represented as $(n)$ and $M'' \subset M'$ iff the generator for $M'$ is a divisor of $M''$. It follows that if we have $M_1 \subset M_2 \subset \cdots$ where $M_1 = (n_1)$ then since $n_1$ has a finite number of divisors it follows that this sequence must terminate after a finite number of steps.

We show that $M$ is non-artinian as follows. consider the decreasing sequence of submodules $(2^n)$ for $n \geq 1$ (this is the module consisting of all positive and negative multiples of $2^n$. Clearly $(2^{n+1}) \subset (2^n)$. This sequence never terminates, since $2^n \notin (2^{n+1})$.

(b) Prove that the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (p^{-n}\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z})$ is artinian and non-noetherian.

Thanks to Alexander Golys for his detailed answer. My solution is now as follows:

To show that $M$ is artian we first note that for s a submodule $M'$ if $a/p^r$ is the element of $M'$ with the smallest magnitude, then $p^r M'$ is a submodule of the module given in part (a). Thus the generators of $M$ are given in the form $(a/p^r)$. Let $a'/p^{r'}$ and $a''/p^{r''}$ be generators for  and $M'$ and $M''$ respectively. Then $M' \subset M''$ iff $a''|a'$ and $r'' \leq r'$. Thus if $M_1 = (a/r)\supset M_2 \supset M_3\supset \cdots$ then this sequence must terminate since there are finitely many nonnegative integers less then $r$ and finitely many divisors of $a$.

We show that $M$ is non-noetherian as follows. consider the increasing sequence of submodules $(\frac{1}{p^n})$ for $n \geq 1$ (this is the module consisting of integer multiples of $\frac{1}{p^n}$. Clearly $(\frac{1}{p^n}) \subset (\frac{1}{p^{n+1}})$. This sequence never terminates, since $\frac{1}{p^{n+1}} \notin (\frac{1}{p^n})$.

Comment: A $\mathbb Z$-module is just an Abelian group. There is no multiplication between two elements of a module, in general.

Comment: doesn't a module need to be a multiplicative monoid though?

Comment: There is multiplication between two elements of a _ring_.

Comment: Any subgroup of $\Bbb{Z}$ is automatically an ideal.   @Math_Day

Comment: @Math_Day - A module is like a weakened version of a vector space (the _scalars_ need only form a ring, not a field). The "vectors" (i.e. module element) only get _added_ to each other, not multiplied by each other, just like vectors don't get multiplied by each other.

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense why people tend to look at modules like vector spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addition in $M$ is just the usual addition of fractions. It is done via the formula
$$
\left(\frac ap + \mathbb Z\right) + \left(\frac b{p^2} + \mathbb Z\right) = \frac{ap + b}{p^2} + \mathbb Z
$$
The multiplication of these elements is not well-defined, since $M$ is a module, not a ring. We only require the multiplication with elements of $\mathbb Z$, which is also done as usual
$$ n\left(\frac ap + \mathbb Z\right) = \frac {na}p + \mathbb Z$$

More formally, this construction of modules as a set-theoretical union $M = \bigcup M_i$ makes sense only where we have canonical inclusions of consecutive summands $i_n: M_n \hookrightarrow M_{n+1}$. In case of finitely many summands the result is trivially isomorphic to the last one, but for infinite families the result is a minimal module including all from the sequence. To state this formally, one can use the notion of a direct limit
$$
M = \varinjlim (M_1 \hookrightarrow M_2 \hookrightarrow \cdots)
$$

In the case of $M_n = \left(\frac 1{p^n}\mathbb Z\right)/\mathbb Z$, we have a canonical inclusion $i_n\left(\frac a{p^n}\right) = \frac{ap}{p^{n+1}} \in M_{n+1}$.

The addition in such direct limits are formally defined using the inclusions. Given $a \in M_n$ and $b \in M_{n+1}$, their sum can be computed as element of $M_{n+1}$ by the formula $a+b = i_n(a) + b$.
Composition of inclusions provide the obvious extension to elements from any two summands, thus all elements from the module. Let denote the composed inclusions as $i_{n, k}: M_n \hookrightarrow M_k$ for $k \ge n$.

Finally, since direct limits of modules are equipped with morphisms $f_n: M_n \hookrightarrow M$ (induced from inclusion of underlying set to the union). To make everything completely formal, we then may define the addition in $M$ as
$$
a + b = f_n(a') + f_m(b') = f_m(i_{n, k}(a')) + f_m(b') = f_m(i_{n, k}(a') + b') 
$$

Where $m \ge n$, and $a'\in M_n, b'\in M_m$ are unique elements sent to $a, b \in M$.

In the same way the action of $\mathbb Z$ is understood:

$$
n\cdot a = n\cdot f_n(a') = f_n(n\cdot a')
$$

Comment: Thank you for the details I've included what I believe should be a complete solution in my post